# The graph of the following equation does not seem right

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to graph the equation [image] using `pgfplots`, whose graph should be a simple closed curve. I have used the following codes:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-1,xmax=3,
ymin=-2,ymax=2,
y=2cm,
x=2cm,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
axis line style=<->,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[no marks,blue] expression[domain=0:2,samples=2500]{(2*x^3-x^4)^(0.125)};
\addplot[no marks,blue] expression[domain=0:2,samples=2500]{-(2*x^3-x^4)^(0.125)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

But the graph looks like

[image]

which is not closed. Any suggestions?

Comment: One possibility would be to use LuaLaTeX and using the Lua backend of PGFPlots by adding `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}` (or higher) to the preamble.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `samples at` to ensure that you get a point for `x=2`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\begin{axis}[
xmin=-1,xmax=3,
ymin=-2,ymax=2,
y=2cm,
x=2cm,
axis x line=middle,
axis y line=middle,
axis line style=<->,
xlabel={$x$},
ylabel={$y$},
]
\addplot[no marks,blue] expression[samples at={0,0.01,...,0.5,0.6,0.7,...,1.91,1.915,1.92,...,1.99,2}]{(2*x^3-x^4)^(0.125)};
\addplot[no marks,blue] expression[samples at={0,0.01,...,0.5,0.6,0.7,...,1.91,1.92,1.93,...,1.99,2}]{-(2*x^3-x^4)^(0.125)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks perfect! Thank you for your answer!